# Prestashop bring cart content to the front page

Tags: prestashop

[image]
I want to remove cart button and display the added items to the cart in the top of the page. So it's always visible
So far I have no luck of finding the function I need to override. tried searching in ps_shoppingcart.php
maybe someone knows exactly what should I do to accomplish this mission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour retirer le bouton du panier il faut "décrocher" le hook du bouton du panier dans "Apparence > Positions"

Pour la liste des articles, le plus simple serait de créer un petit module qui prendrait en charge un hook pour "s'accrocher" a la place du bouton du panier, et qui listerait les elements du panier (avec un foreach par exemple)